# Error while returning a string from a function

Tags: blockchain, solidity, tokenuri

I'm trying to make a function that returns `string` from `mapping(uint256 => string) typeToURI;` but I keep getting an error from `Remix Ethereum IDE`:

`TypeError: Return argument type uint256[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) string memory. --> NFT Minter.sol:88:16: | 88 | return typeToToken[tokenType]; | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`

I know I should use the `memory` type somewhere to fix this issue but I don't know where.

I have tried putting `memory` type in mapping : `mapping(uint256 => memory string) typeToURI;` but it didn't worked and it causes another error.

source code:

```
mapping(uint256 => string) tokenToURI;


function tokenTypeURI(uint256 tokenType) public
    returns (string memory)
{
    return typeToToken[tokenType];
}
```

Comment: hello you have declared mapping as tokenToURI. So, you need return as the same name like  tokenToURI[tokenType]. try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a missundrestanding that instead of `typeToURI` I used another mapping `typeToToken`.

So there is no need to do any conversations between `string memory` and `memory`.

the code for refrence:

```
mapping(uint256 => string) tokenToURI;

function tokenTypeURI(uint256 tokenType) public
    returns (string memory)
{
    return typeToToken[tokenType];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing wrong variable.
fix typeToToken[tokenType] to tokenToURI[tokenType]